# How to set a Javascript variable from my View using a ViewBag property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to set a JavaScript variable in my view (inside a script block) based on the existences of a ViewBag property from the controller... like:

```
var doAboutTab = @(ViewBag.DoAboutTab != null)
```

This generates a JavaScript error of:

var doAboutTab = False

'False is not defined'

Answer (score 5):

```
@if(ViewBag.DoAboutTab != null)
{
    var doAboutTab ="something";
}else
{
    var doAboutTab ="something_else";
}
```

**or**

```
var doAboutTab = '@ViewBag.DoAboutTab' !== '';
```

Comment: I get numerous syntax errors starting with 'Expected constant' against the ViewBag

Comment: could u show ur view, i just tested this code and worked perfectly.

Comment: Excellent you second solution works like a champ ... thanks a million!

Comment: second solution is for a boolean value, while first is for some complex data.

Answer (score 2):

The **false** keyword is lower case in javascript.

```
var doAboutTab = @((ViewBag.DoAboutTab != null).ToString().ToLower());
```

Comment: No problem. It took me about a week before I really understood all of it nuances.

Answer (score 1):

ToString() method on bool in C# returns it as "False".Javascript expects "false", you should make it lowercase

```
var doAboutTab = @((ViewBag.DoAboutTab != null).ToString().ToLower())
```

Comment: @Pablo Strange, I updated the code with explicit razor expression. Try again please

Comment: @Romias "@:" is for displaying plain text inside server side code.

Comment: Ufuk the error I got was from the ToLowerCase() which I think needs to be ToLower()